# Linq Select that will generate tied scores for similar values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, .net-4.5

I'm trying to generate a simple league table with positional numbers based on scores.

e.g. Given the following

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>() {
    new Player { Name = "John", Score = 2 },
    new Player { Name = "Mary", Score = 1 },
    new Player { Name = "Bob", Score = 2 },
    new Player { Name = "Alice", Score = 3 },
};

var results = players
      .OrderByDescending(o => o.Score)
      .Select((v,i) => new { Name = v.Name, Score = v.Score, Position = i+1} );
```

The Results would be.

```
Name  Score Pos
Alice 3     1 
John  2     2 
Bob   2     3 
Mary  1     4
```

Instead, I'd like the result to be

```
Name  Score Pos
Alice 3     1 
John  2     2 
Bob   2     2 <---- this guy is tied for second 
Mary  1     4 <---- this one still comes fourth
```

Is there anyway to access the previous or next elements during a Linq Select so you know whether to increment or decrement the index value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like this do the trick for you?

```
  .Select((v,i) => new { Name = v.Name, 
                         Score = v.Score, 
                         Position = 
                            players.Count(p => p.Score > v.Score) + 1
                       }
         );
```

Comment: I just count the position by adding 1 to the number of players with an even better score.

Comment: By the way, the index i is no longer necessary in (v,i).

Answer (score 3):

it but sounds like you want to do a group by/selectmany

```
      var results = players
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.Score)
              .GroupBy(o => o.Score)
              .SelectMany((l, i) => l.Select(v => new { Name = v.Name, Score = v.Score, Position = i + 1 }));
```

Comment: You beat me by a bit.  That works.  (just tried it in LinqPad).  Forgot about the SelectMany with Index, tried to do it in the GroupBy

Comment: This one shows Mary in 3rd position, when she should be 4th. https://dotnetfiddle.net/XQ9q0H

Comment: @JamesCurran Me too trying in linqpad with GroupBy, about to post it. but he beat us :( +1 ed :)

Comment: close but mary should be 4th, not 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have the solution with the indexed select statement, sort the dataset first though.

**Edit:** Made a small edit because I had the sorter in the wrong order, i.e. it sorted in the ascending order.

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>() {
    new Player { Name = "John", Score = 2 },
    new Player { Name = "Mary", Score = 1 },
    new Player { Name = "Bob", Score = 2 },
    new Player { Name = "Alice", Score = 3 },
};

players.Sort(delegate(Player x, Player y)
{
    return y.Score.CompareTo(x.Score);
});

var results = players
      .Select((v,i) => new { 
        Name = v.Name, 
        Score = v.Score, 
        Position = i+1, 
        TiedWithPrevious = i > 0 && players[i-1].Score == v.Score, 
        TiedWithNext = i < players.Count-1 && players[i+1].Score == v.Score } );
```

Comment: TiedWithNext & TiedWithPrevious are giving the same values, with TiedWithPrevious being incorrect.

Comment: Ahh, I see I had the sort order backwards, I've updated the sort delegate. Looks fine now.